# Proof that horizontal subspace is complementary to vertical subspace in a principal bundle with connection

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, stochastic-analysis

Let $F(M)$ be a principal bundle over a smooth manifold $M$, with a connection $\nabla$. Let $\pi: F(M) \to M$ be the projection. I am working to prove a theorem related to the horizontal and vertical subspaces in this context, and I would like to know how to rigorously show that these subspaces are complementary.

**Definitions:**

1. **Vertical subspace:** The vertical subspace at a point $p$ in $F(M)$ is the kernel of the differential of the projection, i.e., $V_p F(M) = \ker d\pi_{F(M)}$.
2. **Horizontal subspace (given connection $\nabla$):** A curve $\{u_t\}$ in $F(M)$ is called horizontal if for each $e \in \mathbb{R}^d$ the vector field $\{u_te\}$ is parallel along $\{\pi u_t\}$ on $M$. The horizontal subspace at a point $p$ in $F(M)$ consists of the tangent vectors to such horizontal curves.

**Theorem to prove:**

The horizontal subspace is complementary to the vertical subspace in the tangent space of the bundle. Specifically:

- $V_p F(M) \cap H_p F(M) = \{0\}$.
- $\dim(V_p F(M)) + \dim(H_p F(M)) = \dim(T_p F(M))$.

**Attempted proof:**

I have tried to approach this by examining the properties of vectors that are both horizontal and vertical and by using parallel transport, but I found the proof to be elusive.

Could anyone provide guidance or a reference to a rigorous proof that the horizontal and vertical subspaces are complementary in this setting, given the above definitions? Thank you!

**References**

The following source states both the above definition of horizontal subspace and then states the theorem I have given as a fact:

Hsu, E. P. (2002). *Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds*. American Mathematical Society. p. 38.

**Note**

This question was originally asked on MathOverflow and was migrated to StackExchange. I am reposting it so that it gets a chance to be seen

Comment: The important question to ask yourself is: what does it mean for a curve to be horizontal? What properties can you deduce from this?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$Here is a more detailed version:

Let $E(M)$ be a vector bundle with canonical projection $\pi: E(M) \rightarrow M$. Let $\nabla$ be a connection. In other words, for any $p \in M$, open neighborhood $O \subset M$ of $p$, and local section $s: O \rightarrow E(M)$ (so $\pi\circ s$ is the identity map on $O$), there is a linear map
\begin{align*}
  T_pM &\rightarrow E_p(M)\\
  X &\mapsto (\nabla_Xs)(p)
\end{align*}
that satisfies the following: For any smooth $\phi: O \rightarrow \R$,
$$
  (\nabla_X(s\phi))(p) = (\nabla_Xs)(p)\phi(p) + s(p)\langle d\phi(p), X\rangle.
$$

Let $F(M)$ be the frame bundle of $E$ and $f = (f_1, \dots, f_m): O \rightarrow F(M)$ be a local section of $F(M)$ (so $\pi\circ f$ is the identity map on $O$). Then the connection defines a linear map
\begin{align*}
  T_pM &\rightarrow gl(m)\\
  X &\mapsto A,
\end{align*}
where
$$
(\nabla_Xf_j)(p) = f_i(p)A^i_j.
$$
This can be written in matrix form as
$$
(\nabla_Xf)(p) = f(p)A.
$$
This linear map defines a matrix of $1$-forms $\Gamma^i_j$ on $O$, where
$$ \langle \Gamma^i_j,X\rangle = A^i_j $$
and therefore
$$
\nabla_Xf_j = f_i\langle \Gamma^i_j,X\rangle
$$
or in matrix form,
$$
\nabla_Xf = f\langle\Gamma,X\rangle.
$$
For each $X \in T_pM$, let $\gamma: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow M$ be a curve such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=X$. A map $f: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow F(M)$ is a frame along $\gamma$ if $\pi\circ f = \gamma$. The frame is parallel along $\gamma$ if
$$
  \nabla_{\gamma'}f = 0.
$$

Given $p \in M$, $f_0 \in F_p(M)$, and $\gamma: (-\delta,\delta)$, there is a unique parallel frame $f: (-\delta,\delta)\rightarrow F(M)$ along $\gamma$ such that $f(0)=f_0$. This can be shown as follows.

Let $\bar f$ be a frame over $O$ such that $\bar f(p) = f_0$ and $\overline\Gamma$ be the matrix of connection $1$-forms asdefined above. Any frame $f$ along $\gamma$ can be written as
$$
f(t) = \bar f(\gamma(t))L(t),
$$
where $L: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow GL(m)$.
If $f$ is parallel along $\gamma$, then
\begin{align*}
  0 &= \nabla_{\gamma'}f\\
    &= \nabla_{\gamma'}(\bar f L)\\
    &= (\nabla_{\gamma'}\bar f)L + \bar f L'\\
    &= \bar f(\langle\overline\Gamma, \gamma'\rangle L + L').
\end{align*}
In other words, $f$ is parallel along $\gamma$ if and only if
$$
  L' + \langle\overline\Gamma, \gamma'\rangle L = 0.
$$
By the standard existence and uniqueness theorem of ODEs, there exists a unique solution $L: (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow GL(m)$ such that $L(0)=I$. This implies the existence and uniqueness of the parallel frame $f$ along $\gamma$ such that $f(0)=f_0$.

The derivative of the parallel frame $f$ at $p$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f'(0) &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(\bar f(\gamma(t))L(t))\\
&= d\bar f_p\gamma'(0)L(0) + \bar f(p)L'(0)\\
&= d\bar f_p X - \bar f(p)\langle\overline\Gamma, X\rangle.
\end{align*}
This shows that the map
\begin{align*}
  h_p: T_pM &\rightarrow T_{f_0}F(M)\\
  X &\mapsto f'(0)
\end{align*}
is independent of the curve $\gamma$ (as long as $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=X$) and is linear. The horizontal subspace at $f_0$ is defined to be
$$ H_{f_0} = h_p(T_pM). $$
Moreover, since $\pi\circ f(t) = \gamma(t)$,
$$
d\pi_{f_0}h_p(X) = d\pi_{f_0}f'(0) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\pi(f(t)) = \gamma'(0) = X.
$$
Therefore, $h_p$ is injective and the horizontal subspace is complementary to vertical subspace $V_{f_0}F(M) = T_{f_0}F_p(M) = \ker d\pi_{f_0}$.

Comment: I’m not sure how to prove that horizontal lifts exist, but even if I did, I can’t see how your last sentence relates the hypotheses of my theorem with its conclusions. I can’t see my hypotheses appearing in your answer, nor can I see the conclusions of my theorem. Thanks for your answer however

Comment: you have to solve an ODE